# Exception handling issue in ruby

Tags: ruby

In the following code i want to handle the exception.if `msg[0]` not found i have to catch that exception message `msg[2]` in rescue and if it is found put the success message `msg[1]`

```
puts "Verifying Home Page"
 def verifyHomepage(*args)
 begin
  args.each do |msg|    
    page.find(msg[0])
    puts msg[1]
    rescue
    puts msg[2]      
  end
end
end
verifyHomepage(['#logoAnchorr', 'logo anchor found', 'Logo anchor not Found'], ['.navbar-inner', 'Header Bar found', 'Header Bar  not Found'])
```

In the above code iam getting
 `error sysntax error unexpected keyword rescue expecting keyword end`

Comment: Is it because the `rescue` is inside the `args.each` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salil has pointed you where to fix,that's correct. Now The below approach also you could adapt:

```
puts "Verifying Home Page"

def verifyHomepage(*args)
  args.each do |msg|   
    next puts(msg[1]) if page.find(msg[0]) rescue nil  
    puts msg[2]     
  end
end
a = [['#logoAnchorr', 'logo anchor found', 'Logo anchor not Found'], ['.navbar-inner', 'Header Bar found', 'Header Bar  not Found']]
verifyHomepage(*a)
```

***Output:***

```
Verifying Home Page
Logo anchor not Found
Header Bar  not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `begin` inside the `block`

```
puts "Verifying Home Page"
def verifyHomepage(*args)  
    args.each do |msg|
      begin
        page.find(msg[0])
        puts msg[1]
      rescue
        puts msg[2]
    end
  end
end
verifyHomepage(['#logoAnchorr', 'logo anchor found', 'Logo anchor not Found'], ['.navbar-inner', 'Header Bar found', 'Header Bar  not Found'])
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to have an `end` after the `rescue` statement, at all?

Comment: Yes i agree with you @summea